# controller doesn't see disks on a external JBOD chassis

Tags: sas, lsi, supermicro, jbod

I have an [LSI SAS9300-4i4e](https://www.broadcom.com/products/storage/host-bus-adapters/sas-9300-4i4e) controller, plugged into a [SuperServer 6018U-TRTP+](https://www.supermicro.com/products/system/1u/6018/sys-6018u-trtp_.cfm) server and connected with mini-sasHD cable to a [Supermicro SC216BE1C-R741JBOD chassis](https://www.supermicro.nl/products/chassis/2U/216/SC216BE1C-R741JBOD), which has several Toshiba SSD disks installed. The controller doesn't see any disks (it reports it in it's configuration utility, when OS is booted it doesn't see any diosks too). What is even worse, I have two pairs of such equipment, and both are installed on a remote site. I have IPMI connectivity with both servers and JBOD chassises, and I'm out of ideas what may be wrong. I'm also running the identical server + JBOD chassis in another datacenter, with same controler (same cable of course), and this installation is fully functional.

So far I can tell that:

- JBOD chassis is powered up, disks are flashing with their LEDs (thusthey are receiving the power at least)
- server is powered up for sure :)
- the LSI controller runs the latest firmware (13.x) and the latest BIOS
- the JBOD is connected to a proper server and the server has only one controller installed, holding only one external port, so there is no chance that I'm looking for disks on the wrong controller.

Am I right assuming that though JBOD chassis has an IPMI firmware too, this has nothing to do with the problem, thus it's upgrade (so far, however, I'm not seeing any IPMI firmware update for the JBOD) won't help ?

If anyone of you guys have any ideas on what to check, please feel free to describe it in the form of reply or in comments. I'm open to any decent ideas.